# FOREIGN KEY example: The return errmsg of sqlite3_errmsg() for using sqlite3_exec() is not the same as for using sqlite3_step() and sqlite3_bind()

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

Two tables (Teachers and Students) are created while the Id in Students is referenced to the TeacherId in Teachers using FOREIGN KEY. If we use two different methods to insert the values into Students: 
1. sqlite3_exec(); 
2. sqlite3_bind();
The return message from sqlite3_errmsg() is not the same using these two methods:
1. sqlite3_exec(): return "foreign key constraints failed";
2. sqlite3_bind(): return "SQL logic error or missing database";

The message from sqlite3_errmsg() for sqlite3_exec() is more clearer than that for sqlite3_bind();
However, sqlite3_bind() is more convenient and efficient to insert values compared to sqlite3_exec();

My question: How to get a clearer returned error message for sqlite3_bind()?

The following is the full codes:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

using namespace std;

sqlite3* db;

int first_row;

// callback function;
int select_callback(void *p_data, int num_fields, char **p_fields, char **p_col_names)
{
    int i;
    int* nof_records = (int*) p_data;
    (*nof_records)++;

    // first_row was defined in <select_stmt> function;
    // if first_row == 1, print the first row
    // and then set first_row = 0 to avoid the subsequent execution for the following rows.
    if (first_row == 1)
    {
        first_row = 0;
        for (i=0; i < num_fields; i++)
        {   printf("%20s", p_col_names[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (i=0; i< num_fields*20; i++)
        {   printf("=");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i < num_fields; i++)
    {   if (p_fields[i])
        {   printf("%20s", p_fields[i]);
        }
        else
        {   printf("%20s", " ");
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

// With callback function;
void select_stmt(const char* stmt)
{   char *errmsg;
    int   ret;
    int   nrecs = 0;
    first_row = 1;
    ret = sqlite3_exec(db, stmt, select_callback, &nrecs, &errmsg);

    if(ret!=SQLITE_OK)
    {   printf("Error in select statement %s [%s].\n", stmt, errmsg);
    }
    else
    {   printf("\n   %d records returned.\n", nrecs);
    }
}

// Without callback function;
void sql_stmt(const char* stmt)
{   char *errmsg;
    int   ret;
    ret = sqlite3_exec(db, stmt, 0, 0, &errmsg);

    if(ret != SQLITE_OK)
    {   printf("Error in statement: %s [%s].\n", stmt, errmsg);
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////// Main /////////////////////////////////
int main()
{   cout << "sqlite3_open("", &db): " << sqlite3_open("./shcool.db", &db) << endl;

    if(db == 0)
    {   printf("\nCould not open database.");
        return 1;
    }
    char *errmsg;

    int result;
    result = sqlite3_exec ( db,
                            "Drop TABLE IF EXISTS Teachers",  // stmt
                            0,
                            0,
                            &errmsg
                          );
    if ( result != SQLITE_OK )
    {   cout << "\nCould not prepare statement: Drop TABLE: " << result << endl;
        cout << "errmsg: " << errmsg << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    result = sqlite3_exec ( db,
                            "Drop TABLE IF EXISTS Students",  // stmt
                            0,
                            0,
                            &errmsg
                          );
    if ( result != SQLITE_OK )
    {   cout << "\nCould not prepare statement: Drop TABLE: " << result << endl;
        cout << "errmsg: " << errmsg << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    // CREATE TABLE Teachers;
    sql_stmt("CREATE TABLE Teachers(Id integer PRIMARY KEY,Name text,Age integer NOT NULL)");



    //////////////////////////// insert values into Teachers; /////////////////////////////////
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare(db, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;", -1, &stmt, 0);

    if ( sqlite3_prepare
            ( db,
              "insert into Teachers values (:Id,:Name,:Age)",  // stmt
              -1, // If than zero, then stmt is read up to the first nul terminator
              &stmt,
              0  // Pointer to unused portion of stmt
            )
            != SQLITE_OK )
    {   printf("\nCould not prepare statement.");
        return 1;
    }

    int index1, index2, index3;
    index1 =  sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":Id");
    index2 =  sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":Name");
    index3 =  sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":Age");

    cout << index1 << endl;
    cout << index2 << endl;
    cout << index3 << endl;

    printf("\nThe statement has %d wildcards\n", sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(stmt));

    int id[] = {1, 2, 3};
    string name[] = {"Zhang", "Hou", "Liu"};
    int age[] = {28, 29, 31};

    for ( int i = 0; i != 3; i++ )
    {   if (sqlite3_bind_int
                (stmt,
                 index1,  // Index of wildcard
                 id[i]
                )
                != SQLITE_OK)
        {   printf("\nCould not bind sqlite3_bind_int.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (sqlite3_bind_text
                ( stmt,
                  index2,  // Index of wildcard
                  name[i].c_str(),
                  strlen(name[i].c_str()),
                  SQLITE_STATIC
                )
                != SQLITE_OK)
        {   printf("\nCould not bind sqlite3_bind_text.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (sqlite3_bind_int
                ( stmt,
                  index3,  // Index of wildcard
                  age[i]
                )
                != SQLITE_OK)
        {   printf("\nCould not bind sqlite3_bind_int.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // execute sqlite3_step(), and check the state of the statement
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
        {   printf("\nCould not step (execute) stmt.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // reset the statement if you want to continue the sqlite3_bind().
        cout << "sqlite3_reset(stmt): " << sqlite3_reset(stmt) << endl;
    }

//////////////////////////// insert values into Students; /////////////////////////////////

    // CREATE TABLE Students;
    sql_stmt("CREATE TABLE Students (Id integer PRIMARY KEY,  TeacherId integer,  FOREIGN KEY(TeacherId) REFERENCES Teachers(id) )" );

    //////// Method 1: use sqlite3_exec to insert values; ////////////
    sql_stmt("INSERT INTO Students Values (0,  1)" );
    sql_stmt("INSERT INTO Students Values (1,  2)" );
    sql_stmt("INSERT INTO Students Values (2,  9)" );
    cout << "sqlite3_errmsg: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;

    //////// Method 2: use sqlite3_bind to insert values; ////////////
    result = sqlite3_exec ( db,
                            "Drop TABLE IF EXISTS Students",  // stmt
                            0,
                            0,
                            &errmsg
                          );
    if ( result != SQLITE_OK )
    {   cout << "\nCould not prepare statement: Drop TABLE: " << result << endl;
        cout << "errmsg: " << errmsg << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // CREATE TABLE Students;
    sql_stmt("CREATE TABLE Students (Id integer PRIMARY KEY,  TeacherId integer,  FOREIGN KEY(TeacherId) REFERENCES Teachers(id) )" );


    if ( sqlite3_prepare
            ( db,
              "insert into Students values ( :Id,:TeacherId )",  // stmt
              -1, // If than zero, then stmt is read up to the first nul terminator
              &stmt,
              0  // Pointer to unused portion of stmt
            )
            != SQLITE_OK )
    {   printf("\nCould not prepare statement.");
        return 1;
    }

    index1 =  sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":Id");
    index2 =  sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":TeacherId");

    cout << index1 << endl;
    cout << index2 << endl;

    printf("\nThe statement has %d wildcards\n", sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(stmt));

    int studentId[] = {0, 1, 2};
    /// if the FOREIGN KEY works, the teacherId should not be 9;
    int teacherId[] = {1, 2, 9};

    for ( int i = 0; i != 3; i++ )
    {   if (sqlite3_bind_int
                (stmt,
                 index1,  // Index of wildcard
                 studentId[i]
                )
                != SQLITE_OK)
        {   printf("\nCould not bind sqlite3_bind_int.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (sqlite3_bind_int
                ( stmt,
                  index2,  // Index of wildcard
                  teacherId[i]
                )
                != SQLITE_OK)
        {   printf("\nCould not bind sqlite3_bind_int.\n");
            cout << "sqlite3_errmsg: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        // execute sqlite3_step(), and check the state of the statement

//        cout << "sqlite3_errmsg: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
        if (  result = sqlite3_step(stmt)  != SQLITE_DONE )
        {   printf("\nCould not step (execute) stmt.\n");
            cout << "sqlite3_errmsg: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
            cout << "result: " << result << endl;
            return 1;
        }


        cout << "result: " << result << endl;
        // reset the statement if you want to continue the sqlite3_bind().
        cout << "sqlite3_reset(stmt): " << sqlite3_reset(stmt) << endl;
    }

    printf("\n");

    // Print all;
    select_stmt("select * from Teachers");
    select_stmt("select * from Students");

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [recommended](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) to use `sqlite3_prepare_v2` instead of `sqlite3_prepare`. Excerpt:

> The sqlite3_prepare_v2() and sqlite3_prepare16_v2() interfaces are recommended for all new programs. The two older interfaces are retained for backwards compatibility, but their use is discouraged. In the "v2" interfaces, the prepared statement that is returned (the sqlite3_stmt object) contains a copy of the original SQL text. This causes the sqlite3_step() interface to behave differently in three ways:

[Point 1 omitted]

> 2.   When an error occurs, sqlite3_step() will return one of the detailed error codes or extended error codes. The legacy behavior was that sqlite3_step() would only return a generic SQLITE_ERROR result code and the application would have to make a second call to sqlite3_reset() in order to find the underlying cause of the problem. With the "v2" prepare interfaces, the underlying reason for the error is returned immediately.

[Point 3 omitted]

Comment: I have added "_v2" after sqlite3_prepare, then the error message became the same as using sqlite3_exec.  Another thing, could you append the point1 and point3 since they are omitted. Thanks.

Comment: @zongshiwujie I omitted them because they were not relevant to the current question.